# Android score is reset to zero when phone sleeps

Tags: android

My first stackoverflow post.

I've had a free scoring app on the Play store for about a year now, but a user recently pointed out that the score resets to zero when the phone goes to sleep. And he's right. From what I've read, I'm guessing my issue has to do with savedInstanceState.

The actual code that increases/decreases the score is sitting outside of savedInstanceState ... but whenever I try to address that, I get errors. Before I go to far down this path, I thought I better let the experts weight in. Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
package com.estrellastudios.rally.point.free;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class KeepScore extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {

    // declare a few variables on outer side of code
    TextView tvhs, tvvs, tvho, tvvo;
    ImageButton homeAddButton, homeSubtractButton, 
    visitorAddButton, visitorSubtractButton;
    Button reset;   
    int scoreH;
    int scoreV;





    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.keepscore);

        //declare all the buttons
        homeAddButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_add_button);
        visitorAddButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.visitor_add_button);
        homeSubtractButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_subtract);
        visitorSubtractButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.visitor_subtract);
        reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);



        // declare the home & visitor scores
        tvhs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.home_score);
        tvvs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.visitor_score); 


        // declare the home & visitor teams
        TextView tvho = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.home_output);
        TextView tvvo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.visitor_output);            
        tvho.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("homeText"));
        tvvo.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("visitorText")); 


        homeAddButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        homeSubtractButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        visitorAddButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        visitorSubtractButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);





            // ChunkFive                  
            // team name styling and output here
            Typeface Chunkfive = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Chunkfive.ttf");

            tvho.setTypeface(Chunkfive);
            //tvho.setTextSize(29.f);               
            tvvo.setTypeface(Chunkfive);
            //tvvo.setTextSize(29.f);

            // ChunkFive
            // Scoring styling and output here
            tvhs.setTypeface(Chunkfive);
            //tvhs.setTextSize(120.f);        
            tvvs.setTypeface(Chunkfive);
            //tvvs.setTextSize(120.f);


            tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
            tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));

    }



         // start view

            public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean showTextH = false;
            boolean showTextV = false;


             // start switch case   

            if(scoreH==0 && scoreV > 0){
                switch(v.getId())
                {
                case R.id.home_add_button: scoreH++; showTextH = true; break;
                //case R.id.home_subtract: scoreH--; showTextH = true; break;
                case R.id.visitor_add_button: scoreV++; showTextV = true; break;
                case R.id.visitor_subtract: scoreV--; showTextV = true; break;
                }
                if(showTextH)
                    tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
                    tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
                if(showTextV)
                    tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
                    tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));


                // end switch case


            }

            else if(scoreV==0 && scoreH > 0){

                switch(v.getId())
                {
                case R.id.home_add_button: scoreH++; showTextH = true; break;
                case R.id.home_subtract: scoreH--; showTextH = true; break;
                case R.id.visitor_add_button: scoreV++; showTextV = true; break;
                //case R.id.visitor_subtract: scoreV--; showTextV = true; break;
                }
                if(showTextH)
                    tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
                    tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
                if(showTextV)
                    tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
                    tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));



                // end switch case

            }


            else if(scoreV==0 && scoreH==0){

                switch(v.getId())
                {
                case R.id.home_add_button: scoreH++; showTextH = true; break;
                //case R.id.home_subtract: scoreH--; showTextH = true; break;
                case R.id.visitor_add_button: scoreV++; showTextV = true; break;
                //case R.id.visitor_subtract: scoreV--; showTextV = true; break;
                }
                if(showTextH)
                    tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
                    tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
                if(showTextV)
                    tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
                    tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));


                // end switch case

            }

            else {

            switch(v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.home_add_button: scoreH++; showTextH = true; break;
            case R.id.home_subtract: scoreH--; showTextH = true; break;
            case R.id.visitor_add_button: scoreV++; showTextV = true; break;
            case R.id.visitor_subtract: scoreV--; showTextV = true; break;
            }
            if(showTextH)
                tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
                tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
            if(showTextV)
                tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
                tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));


            // end switch case

            }





            // reset button
            reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    scoreH = 0;
                    scoreV = 0;
                    tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
                    tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
                }

            });

            //end reset button


            }  // end public void onClick


    @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
            tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
        super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
            tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
        super.onResume();
        }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% certain but my guess is that your activity is being destroyed when the phone goes to sleep and recreated when it is opened back up. I would store the scores in Shared preferences every time in one of the scores change and then restore those values from Share Preferences in the onCreate Method. Note that this is will restore the last values used even if it is a new game so you won't to put some more logic in to handle this. Before you do this put a Log.d in your onCreate to see if this is what is happening but would still do this just to be on the safe side. You are never guaranteed that the Activity will remain in memory once the app is background. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

EDIT

Here is your code updated with some Log debugging output so that you can start getting an idea what is happening in LogCat:

```
package com.estrellastudios.rally.point.free;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class KeepScore extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {

// Instance Variables
TextView tvhs, tvvs, tvho, tvvo;
ImageButton homeAddButton, homeSubtractButton, 
visitorAddButton, visitorSubtractButton;
Button reset;   
int scoreH;
int scoreV;
private static final String TAG = KeepScore.class.getSimpleName(); 







@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /*
     * Now you can see every time the onCreate Method
     * is called. The onCreate method is called only when
     * the activity is created. So if this gets called instead
     * of onResume then you now that this activity has been removed
     * from memory and is being recreated.
     */
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate Method Called");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.keepscore);

    //declare all the buttons
    homeAddButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_add_button);
    visitorAddButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.visitor_add_button);
    homeSubtractButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_subtract);
    visitorSubtractButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.visitor_subtract);
    reset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);



    // declare the home & visitor scores
    tvhs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.home_score);
    tvvs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.visitor_score); 


    // declare the home & visitor teams
    TextView tvho = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.home_output);
    TextView tvvo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.visitor_output);            
    tvho.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("homeText"));
    tvvo.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("visitorText")); 


    homeAddButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    homeSubtractButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    visitorAddButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    visitorSubtractButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);





    // ChunkFive                  
    // team name styling and output here
    Typeface Chunkfive = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Chunkfive.ttf");

    tvho.setTypeface(Chunkfive);
    //tvho.setTextSize(29.f);               
    tvvo.setTypeface(Chunkfive);
    //tvvo.setTextSize(29.f);

    // ChunkFive
    // Scoring styling and output here
    tvhs.setTypeface(Chunkfive);
    //tvhs.setTextSize(120.f);        
    tvvs.setTypeface(Chunkfive);
    //tvvs.setTextSize(120.f);

    Log.d(TAG, "Home team score in onCreate: " + scoreH);
    tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
    Log.d(TAG, "Vistor team score in onCreate: " + scoreV);
    tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));

}



// start view

public void onClick(View v) {

    boolean showTextH = false;
    boolean showTextV = false;


    // start switch case   

    if(scoreH==0 && scoreV > 0){
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.home_add_button: scoreH++; showTextH = true; break;
        //case R.id.home_subtract: scoreH--; showTextH = true; break;
        case R.id.visitor_add_button: scoreV++; showTextV = true; break;
        case R.id.visitor_subtract: scoreV--; showTextV = true; break;
        }
        if(showTextH)
            tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
        tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
        if(showTextV)
            tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
        tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));


        // end switch case


    }

    else if(scoreV==0 && scoreH > 0){

        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.home_add_button: scoreH++; showTextH = true; break;
        case R.id.home_subtract: scoreH--; showTextH = true; break;
        case R.id.visitor_add_button: scoreV++; showTextV = true; break;
        //case R.id.visitor_subtract: scoreV--; showTextV = true; break;
        }
        if(showTextH)
            tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
        tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
        if(showTextV)
            tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
        tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));



        // end switch case

    }


    else if(scoreV==0 && scoreH==0){

        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.home_add_button: scoreH++; showTextH = true; break;
        //case R.id.home_subtract: scoreH--; showTextH = true; break;
        case R.id.visitor_add_button: scoreV++; showTextV = true; break;
        //case R.id.visitor_subtract: scoreV--; showTextV = true; break;
        }
        if(showTextH)
            tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
        tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
        if(showTextV)
            tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
        tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));


        // end switch case

    }

    else {

        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.home_add_button: scoreH++; showTextH = true; break;
        case R.id.home_subtract: scoreH--; showTextH = true; break;
        case R.id.visitor_add_button: scoreV++; showTextV = true; break;
        case R.id.visitor_subtract: scoreV--; showTextV = true; break;
        }
        if(showTextH)
            tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
        tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
        if(showTextV)
            tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
        tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));


        // end switch case

    }





    // reset button
    reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            scoreH = 0;
            scoreV = 0;
            tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
            tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
        }

    });

    //end reset button


}  // end public void onClick


@Override
protected void onPause() {

    /*I do no see the point in setting your
     * score text views to the score values when
     * they are already set. I would remove these
     * 2 lines of code.
     */
    tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
    tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {         
    Log.d(TAG, "Home team score in onResume: " + scoreH);
    tvhs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreH));
    Log.d(TAG, "Vistor team score in onResume: " + scoreV);
    tvvs.setText(String.valueOf(scoreV));
    super.onResume();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I thought of one other bit of info ... maybe I should have added this.  

1) my first activity asks the user to enter both team names, then they hit an ok button. 

2)The second activity is this screen, which displays team names and lets the user add/subtract to the score.   

Key note: When the device comes back from sleep mode, the score reverts to zero, but the team names stick.  Thought I'd mention that in case it's important.

Comment: The only difference I see between the team names and scores ins that you your setting the scores TextView's from your instances variables but not you the team names. Again, I would use some Log out put to see what your variables and before setting the text views and also to see what method's are getting called. My guess is that your activity is being destroyed and recreated. Since you are setting you team names TextView's from intent extra's then the OS retains intent used to create the Activity and so your team names get properly set in onCreate with those two lines of code.

Comment: Thanks Lentz. I'll look into this a bit more, including how to do a Log.d

Comment: Add this instance variable
private static final String TAG = YourClassName.class.getSimpleName();

and then just 
Log.d(TAG, "Something got called");
Log.d(TAG, "My varible = " + myVariable);

Comment: Sorry, Lentz. You're worlds further along than I am. I'd just be copying and pasting your code from above, and not really understanding what it's doing.

Comment: I just updated my answer and added some Log debugging output in it so you can see what is being called and what the values of your score instance variables are in on resume and onCreate. They should not be initiated in onCreate because you declare them but have not initiated them yet.

Comment: @pliske That's bad programming then.  Learn new things. Ask about specific lines of code. Look at the documentation. Troubleshoot. Don't just copy and paste code blindly.

Comment: Agreed. Do lots of googling. You should also read about Activity lifecycles so that you have better idea of what is happening with your code and why it is being destroyed and recreated. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I added that. I see what you mean in the logs now. When I change the score to H=2 and V=4, and then I hit, say, the Home button ... the log says "Home team score in onResume: 2 .. and Visitor team score in onResume: 4." But the moment I turn my screen off, the log updates with "onCreate Method called." and then gives me ""Home team score in onCreate: 0 .. and Visitor team score in onCrate: 0." Gives me the same data for onResume.

Comment: Exactly the activity is being destroyed and then recreated. Read this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: @BLaZuRE: Agreed, and that's why I said it. I'd rather NOT do things that way. 

I'm relatively new at this stuff. So I Google, and Stackoverflow and look at the documentation. But I'm also anxious to get better, yet frustrated at how slow it goes. (I think I might need to find a good tutor and pay them!)

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Hey Lentz .. wanted to thank you again. Between your logging trick, reading your Android link, and then adding that log code in various areas (like onCreate) ... I was able to see when the numbers reverted to zero ... or stayed put (when I fixed it).  Works now!!